# How to use easeOutBounce animiation on display block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, animation

So I'd like to use `jQuery ui` effect `easeOutBounce` on my mobile menu, the script goes as follows:

```
$("#navbar-checkbox, .mobile-menu-wrapper .13").click(function(){
  $("#mobile-nav").({ display: 'block' }, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
})
```

but this doesn't work, it doesn't even change the css to `display: block`.

1. How can I use `display block` with animation?
2. Can you please show me how to apply easeOutBounce to it as well

Thank you.

Comment: `$("#mobile-nav").css('display','block').slideDown(600, 'easeOutBounce');` ?

Comment: @urbz add your comment at answer, and approve this for improving SO.

Comment: @Xeen dont forget about approving right answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to use jQuerys [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) style manipulation in order to set the style of the element that is intended to be animated. This is done first.

After that, to get the animation to work as you want it too, you want [`.slideDown()`](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) to be triggered after the css attribute is set on the element, with the `duration` and the specified effect (`easeOutBounce`)

Code snippet:

```
$("#mobile-nav").css('display','block').slideDown(600, 'easeOutBounce');
```